# Getting all the static execution paths to a method VS2013,C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I am trying to find all the static execution paths to a method.

Besides manually trying to walk the tree of "the find all usages/View call hierarchy" is there a way to get all the execution paths that end up calling that method?

I am not looking for dynamic/polymorphic calls, just the static ones is enough.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about how to use Roslyn.

Comment: @itsme86 : seems like I have no choice left, any problem of value that I have points to Roslyn.

Comment: There's always other options. You can, for example, always parse the files manually. I'm not saying I recommend that, but it's an option.

Comment: That's sort of what Microsoft PEX does, maybe check it out to see if you can leverage it for static code paths.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A > Incoming Calls (ReSharper)

Comment: @Matthias That is an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @arjang posted .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper provides the ability to recursively search for execution paths via `Inspect this | Incoming Calls` (default with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A</kbd>).

Comment: Also allows the results to be exported into text, xml, etc. Visual Studio's Ctrl K + Ctrl T does not allow the results to be copied and pasted or exported in any way